# Curl corresponding request in node-fetch

Tags: node.js, react-native, curl, node-fetch

It's been days I've been trying to make this `curl` request work with `node-fetch` without success.

```
curl -X GET 
-u "<username>:<password>" 
--output hello_world.mp3 
"https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize/?accept=audio/mpeg&text=hello"
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

**Note:** I'm using ***React Native***.

Comment: what is the code you have written? what error does it throw? or how does it not work

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if Node.JS has a **BETTER** api to do this (but i'm surprised if it does not), i don't do Node.js programming myself, but i know how to do this with the normal browser javascript API `XMLHttpRequest`, i also know that Node.js support XMLHttpRequest.

the equivalent-ish XMLHttpRequest would be

```
{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize/?accept=audio/mpeg&text=hello", true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("<username>:<password>"));

    xhr.onload = function(ev) {
        fs.appendFile("hello_world.mp3", xhr.response, {
            flag: "wb"
        });
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```